# Minimum of $\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt y+\sqrt z\right)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Minimum Value of $\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt y+\sqrt z\right)^2$ for $x,y,z\in\mathbb R_{>0}$

Original Question is [here](https://brilliant.org/problems/inequality-8/?group=7p9Z0vO0fLXv&ref_id=779701), I applied Titus lemma to reduce it to the form above, but I don't know if it was a good method

If I expand the $2$nd parenthesis then $\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)(x+y+z)\ge 9$

and the remaining part is

$\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)2(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{yz}+\sqrt{zx})$

seems difficult to estimate, was my approach not useful ?

Comment: Can't you just apply Holder's inequality? $$\left(\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}\right)\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z}\right)\geq 3^3.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AM-GM gives
$$\left(\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\right)\left(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{z} \right)^2 \ge \left(\frac3{\sqrt[3]{xyz}}\right)\cdot \left(3\sqrt[6]{xyz} \right)^2=27$$
As equality is possible when $x=y=z$, this is the minimum.

---

On second thought, after checking your link, Holder seems direct for your original problem:
$$\frac12\sum_{cyc}(u+v) \cdot \sum_{cyc} \frac1x \cdot \sum_{cyc} \frac{x}{u+v} \ge \frac{3^3}2$$